# Additives to increase water density and solubility

Tags: water, solubility, density, liquids

What additives do I need to add to a water-based drink (coffee or tea for example), to increase its density and to make the drink insoluble (like olive oil for example) in salt sea water or inland water, and the drink with additives is still consumable?

A little bit like some bar-cocktails with layered liquids. The idea is to serve and drink tea or coffee under water, whilst scubaing with students or tourists, or to kill boredom during mandatory decos. Not sure why I can't find such an answer elsewhere on the internet, given how cool the demand might be..

Comment: [Problem solved](https://www.liquor.com/recipes/b-52/).

Comment: Ok- this is going somewhere- almost. Most of these are alcoholic (cant serve to kids) and aren't indicating if they drop below water? Has anyone tried anything of these?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a drink thicker with [food-safe thickening additives](https://opentextbc.ca/ingredients/chapter/types-of-thickening-agents/), such as pre-gelatinized starches, gelatine, or agar(-agar). Make your beverage *just* thick enough to stay in the glass and resist mixing, and add food coloring, if desired.

There's no safe way to make a water-based drink **insoluble** in water, though. And this doesn't answer the question of **how safe it would be to try to drink while in SCUBA gear under water**. Consider, for example, that at 10 m depth, theoretically, you could exert a force of 2 atmospheres sucking on a straw in the concoction -- likely to pull it up the straw, and also likely to cause damage to the body. After all, if you're in decompression, and form a partial vacuum in your mouth, aren't you inviting air embolism?

Comment: Pooring a thickened water liquid into a cup won't work in water, it will just dissolve but not fall into a cup. This does not answer density or solubility, or solve the purpose of the question. (As for safety: The liquid will be stored in a plastic flexible bottle. Everything will be at the same pressure as the depth- no safety concerns.)